# ReentrantLock Exceptions

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm developing for Android 2.2, and a bit confused as to how ReentrantLocks work.  Can the following code ever throw an IllegalMonitorStateException?  I ask because I don't see how it can--according to the API, tryLock returns true if and only if the lock is successfully obtained--but occasionally the unlock() command does.

```
public void lockDemo() {
    ReentrantLock myLock = new ReentrantLock();
    if (myLock.tryLock()) {
        System.out.println("Lock obtained");
        myLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: The example should not fail. But is your actual code really this simple?

Comment: Yes and no.  The overall program is quite a bit larger, and has about 8 threads running and sharing information.  But the code inside the tryLock() block pretty much is this simple.  I'm either copying primitives to local variables for later manipulation, some mathematical operations, or writing to a printWriter.  As far as I can tell, there's nothing that could mess up the ReentrantLock.

Answer (score 1):

From the javadoc: `unlock()` throws `IllegalMonitorStateException` if the current thread does not hold the lock. I'm guessing you would not be asking unless you are seeing this, but, you should check the stack trace to see what method is triggering it. The example you give won't reproduce this situation, so your real code must be more complex and the problem must lie somewhere in the other bits.

Off the top of my head, I can imagine that maybe the lock is actually being unlocked twice somehow. Or that the lock may not actually be successfully acquired in some code paths that think they have the lock.

Comment: I agree with your assessment, but I have absolutely no idea what other code I could possibly write that would cause this to happen.  AFAIK, If another thread holds the lock, this thread can't obtain it; if this thread holds the lock, it should be able to release it.  Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: That's right but maybe it's released twice? Maybe it's unlocked without holding the lock somehow? Those scenarios. A minute with a debugger tracking calls to methods on that lock should show it.

Answer (score 0):

It might not actually solve your problem, but there's some discussion of something similar here: http://www.jroller.com/ethdsy/entry/reentrantlock_bug

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Like you said, I don't think the solution is applicable to my code, but at least now I know I'm not crazy.

Answer (score 0):

The `tryLock()` mothod takes two parameters, `long timeout, TimeUnit unit`. That could have something to do with it.

I'm not saying that way of using locks is wrong, I've just never used them that way. I've been taught to use locks in this fashion:

```
public void lockDemo() {
    ReentrantLock myLock = new ReentrantLock();
    try {
        myLock.lock();
        // do work...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // catch if something fails
    } finally {
        myLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's also a tryLock() that doesn't take arguments--it just returns false immediately if the lock is unavailable.  I haven't seen many official code samples that use it, though.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#tryLock()